# Improve performance of Pandas subsets/filters with multiple conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, performance, numpy

In my Python script I have a Pandas DataFrame with about 5.2 million rows and 26 columns.

The current analysis I am running tests 1.5 million different subsets/filters against this DataFrame, using multiple conditions (combinations of the columns) to count the total number of occurrences. I've tried multiple methods and improved the speed a bit from my original code, but I believe this could be done faster.

Heres the code with a dummy DataFrame (5.2M rows and 26 columns A-Z) and one example of the subset method I initially used, with multiple conditions:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

np.random.seed(101)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,11,size=(5200000, 26)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'))

cond1 = (df.A > 5)
cond2 = (df.B.shift(1).between(8,10,inclusive=True))
cond3 = (df.C.shift(1) < 5)
cond4 = (df.D.shift(1) == 1)
cond5 = (df.E.shift(1).between(2,5,inclusive=True))

start = time.time()
subsetLength = len(df.loc[cond1 & cond2 & cond3 & cond4 & cond5])
stop = time.time()

print("Length:",subsetLength)
print("Time:", stop - start)
```

The time to retrieve the length of this subset is around 0.030s on my laptop (Macbook Pro 2020 Intel) for each subset/filter:

```
Length: 9781
Time: 0.029639244079589844
```

**Note:** I am using .shift(1) to check previous rows for the columns B - E and for column A this is not the case.

Now 0.030s might seem quite fast, but since I am running 1.5 million of those subsets, the script currently took about 12-13 hours. Therefor, every speed increase I can get at an individual subset/filter can be a huge time saver.

Instead of .loc[] I have also tried .shape[0] and .sum() like this:

**.shape[0]**

```
subsetLength = df[cond1 & cond2 & cond3 & cond4 & cond5].shape[0]
```

This seems to be a bit faster but still was in the range of 0.027s - 0.028s.

**.sum()**

```
subsetLength = (cond1 & cond2 & cond3 & cond4 & cond5).sum()
```

This was around 0.021s, already quite a nice improvement compared to the .loc[] which could save around 4 hours. But still the total would take a lot of hours (around 8 or 9).

**np.where()**

Finally I tried to use np.where(), for this I had to change the conditions a bit:

```
cond1 = (df['A'] > 5)
cond2 = (df['B'].shift(1).between(8,10,inclusive=True))
cond3 = (df['C'].shift(1) < 5)
cond4 = (df['D'].shift(1) == 1)
cond5 = (df['E'].shift(1).between(2,5,inclusive=True))

subsetLength = len(np.where(cond1 & cond2 & cond3 & cond4 & cond5)[0])
```

This took around 0.0195s and was the fastest method I got thus far.

Preferably I am looking for performance in the 0.002s or faster range so the script would take around 1 hour to finish, but I can't tell if this is possible. Any advice on how the speed of this subsetting/filtering a big DataFrame for counts can be improved? Am I perhaps using slow ways to do counts for subsets with multiple conditions? Or is this kind of analysis just heavy and is the time it takes realistic.

Comment: Just as a note for the question, you could set `np.random.seed` to improve the reproducibility of this sample.

Comment: have you tried writing it as a function, and using @Cache?

Comment: Curious, what change to conditions were made for `np.where`? Do note: in pandas, it is preferred to reference columns with standard indexing `[...]` and not periods. See warning in [Attribute Access](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#attribute-access).

Comment: @HenryEcker good point, thanks. Updated the code above accordingly.

Comment: @Aru I did not try that yet. I'll read more about it and will update above if it provided any solution.

Comment: @Parfait I used df['A'], df['B'], etc.. instead of df.A, df.B, etc.. for the np.where version. The conditions used in the np.where version were also posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to perform the logical operation in-place to avoid the creation of many **temporary arrays**:

```py
tmp = np.empty(cond1.shape, dtype=np.bool8)
np.logical_and(cond1, cond2, out=tmp)
np.logical_and(tmp, cond3, out=tmp)
np.logical_and(tmp, cond4, out=tmp)
np.logical_and(tmp, cond5, out=tmp)
subsetLength = tmp.sum()
```

This solution is 2.2 times faster on my machine.

The above solution is not very efficient as it still read and write big arrays in memory. However, I doubt it is possible to do something much faster only with Numpy (since `logical_and` apparently do not provide a way to compute more than 2 elements at a time).

Another, solution is to use **Numba** to avoid the read/write of the temporary array and even run the code in **parallel**. Here is how:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('int64(bool_[::1],bool_[::1],bool_[::1],bool_[::1],bool_[::1])', parallel=True)
def computeSubsetLength(cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4, cond5):
    n = len(cond1)
    assert len(cond2) == n and len(cond3) == n and len(cond4) == n and len(cond5) == n
    subsetLength = 0
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        subsetLength += cond1[i] & cond2[i] & cond3[i] & cond4[i] & cond5[i]
    return subsetLength

subsetLength = computeSubsetLength(cond1.to_numpy(), cond2.to_numpy(), cond3.to_numpy(), cond4.to_numpy(), cond5.to_numpy())
```

This new version is **31 times faster**. It is close to optimal on my machine since it just takes roughly the time to read the arrays in memory (is takes `0.000624 s` while the time to only read the input data from memory is `0.000484 s`).

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this greatly improves the code I currently have. In my case not 31 times but around 10 times, which was exactly the improvement I was looking for. Any thoughts on how our result can differ 21 times (which is quite a gap), could this be because of difference between machines? @jérôme-richard

Comment: @Kcode Yeah, It may come from the hardware as the code should be theoretically memory bound on most machines. On mine, I can reach a throughput close to 40 GiB/s in practice in benchmarks (thanks to 2 DDR4 channels @ 3200MHz). If you have 1 channel @ 2400MHz, then the speed up will be smaller. The number of core also play a role (and CPU cache associativity). Alternatively, it can be due to a less efficient code generated by Numba on your platform. How long does it takes with `range` instead of `nb.prange` and without `parallel=True`? Note that the first run may takes more time than others.

Comment: That seems like a logic explanation. I might have had some other programs open aswell. Tried your alternative, this also works but is a bit slower. Time of the first few was around 0.005, after that it took about 0.003 per subset. Currently I am also working on converting the 1.5 million for loop work with multiprocessing package. So if that works, than in combination with your numba solution the script will be more than fast enough. @jérôme-richard