# Improving the performance of multiple subsets on a large Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numba

I have a dataframe containing 6.3 million records and 111 columns. For this example I've limited the dataframe to 27 columns (A-Z). On this dataframe I am trying to run an analysis in which I use different combinations of the columns (with pairs of 5 columns per combination) and subset each of those on the dataframe and do a count of the number of occurrences for each combination and finally evaluate if this count extends a certain threshold and then store the combination. The code is already optimized with an efficient way of running the individual subsets, using numba. But still the overal script I have takes quite some time (7-8 hours). This is because if you use for example 90 columns (which is my actual number used) to make combinations of 5, you get 43.949.268 different combinations. In my case I also use a shifted versions of some columns (value of day before). So for this example I've limited it to 20 columns (A-J 2 times, including the shifted versions).

The columns used are stored in a list, which is converted to numbers because it otherwise gets to big using long strings. The names in the list corresponds with a dictionary containing the subset variables.

Here is the full code example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import time
from itertools import combinations

# Numba preparation
@nb.njit('int64(bool_[::1],bool_[::1],bool_[::1],bool_[::1],bool_[::1])', parallel=True)
def computeSubsetLength5(cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4, cond5):
    n = len(cond1)
    assert len(cond2) == n and len(cond3) == n and len(cond4) == n and len(cond5) == n
    subsetLength = 0
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        subsetLength += cond1[i] & cond2[i] & cond3[i] & cond4[i] & cond5[i]
    return subsetLength

# Example Dataframe
np.random.seed(101)
bigDF = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,11,size=(6300000, 26)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'))

# Example query list
queryList = ['A_shift0','B_shift0','C_shift0','D_shift0','E_shift0','F_shift0','G_shift0','H_shift0','I_shift0','J_shift0','A_shift1','B_shift1','C_shift1','D_shift1','E_shift1','F_shift1','G_shift1','H_shift1','I_shift1','J_shift1']

# Convert list to numbers for creation combinations
listToNum = list(range(len(queryList)))

# Generate 15504 combinations of the 20 queries without repitition
queryCombinations = combinations(listToNum,5)

# Example query dict
queryDict = {
'query_A_shift0': ((bigDF.A >= 1) & (bigDF.A < 3)),
'query_B_shift0': ((bigDF.B >= 3) & (bigDF.B < 5)),
'query_C_shift0': ((bigDF.C >= 5) & (bigDF.C < 7)),
'query_D_shift0': ((bigDF.D >= 7) & (bigDF.D < 9)),
'query_E_shift0': ((bigDF.E >= 9) & (bigDF.E < 11)),
'query_F_shift0': ((bigDF.F >= 1) & (bigDF.F < 3)),
'query_G_shift0': ((bigDF.G >= 3) & (bigDF.G < 5)),
'query_H_shift0': ((bigDF.H >= 5) & (bigDF.H < 7)),
'query_I_shift0': ((bigDF.I >= 7) & (bigDF.I < 9)),
'query_J_shift0': ((bigDF.J >= 7) & (bigDF.J < 11)),
'query_A_shift1': ((bigDF.A.shift(1) >= 1) & (bigDF.A.shift(1) < 3)),
'query_B_shift1': ((bigDF.B.shift(1) >= 3) & (bigDF.B.shift(1) < 5)),
'query_C_shift1': ((bigDF.C.shift(1) >= 5) & (bigDF.C.shift(1) < 7)),
'query_D_shift1': ((bigDF.D.shift(1) >= 7) & (bigDF.D.shift(1) < 9)),
'query_E_shift1': ((bigDF.E.shift(1) >= 9) & (bigDF.E.shift(1) < 11)),
'query_F_shift1': ((bigDF.F.shift(1) >= 1) & (bigDF.F.shift(1) < 3)),
'query_G_shift1': ((bigDF.G.shift(1) >= 3) & (bigDF.G.shift(1) < 5)),
'query_H_shift1': ((bigDF.H.shift(1) >= 5) & (bigDF.H.shift(1) < 7)),
'query_I_shift1': ((bigDF.I.shift(1) >= 7) & (bigDF.I.shift(1) < 9)),
'query_J_shift1': ((bigDF.J.shift(1) >= 7) & (bigDF.J.shift(1) < 11))
}

totalCountDict = {'queryStrings': [],'totalCounts': []}

# Loop through all query combinations and count subset lengths
start = time.time()
for combi in list(queryCombinations):
    tempList = list(combi)
    queryOne = str(queryList[tempList[0]])
    queryTwo = str(queryList[tempList[1]])
    queryThree = str(queryList[tempList[2]])
    queryFour = str(queryList[tempList[3]])
    queryFive = str(queryList[tempList[4]])

    queryString = '-'.join(map(str,tempList))

    count = computeSubsetLength5(queryDict["query_" + queryOne].to_numpy(), queryDict["query_" + queryTwo].to_numpy(), queryDict["query_" + queryThree].to_numpy(), queryDict["query_" + queryFour].to_numpy(), queryDict["query_" + queryFive].to_numpy())

    if count > 1300:
        totalCountDict['queryStrings'].append(queryString)
        totalCountDict['totalCounts'].append(count)

print(len(totalCountDict['totalCounts']))
stop = time.time()
print("Loop time:", stop - start)
```

This currently takes about 20 seconds on my Macbook Pro 2020 Intel version, for the 15504 combinations. Any thoughts on how this could be improved? I have tried using multiprocessing, but since I am using numba already for the individual subsets this did not work well together. Am I using an inefficient way to do multiple subsets using a list, dictionary and for loop to subset all the combinations, or is 7-8 hours realistic for doing 44 million subsets on a dataframe of 6.3 million records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution to speed up by a large factor this code is to **pack the bits** in the boolean arrays stored in `queryDict`. Indeed, the code `computeSubsetLength5` is likely **memory bound** (I thought the speed-up provided in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67726254/12939557) would be sufficient for the needs).

Here is the function to pack the bits of a boolean array:

```py
@nb.njit('uint64[::1](bool_[::1])')
def toPackedArray(cond):
    n = len(cond)
    res = np.empty((n+63)//64, dtype=np.uint64)

    for i in range(n//64):
        tmp = np.uint64(0)
        for j in range(64):
            tmp |= nb.types.uint64(cond[i*64+j]) << j
        res[i] = tmp

    # Remainder
    if n % 64 > 0:
        tmp = 0
        for j in range(n - (n % 64), n):
            tmp |= cond[j] << j
        res[len(res)-1] = tmp

    return res
```

Note that the end of the arrays are padded with 0 which does not affect the *specific* following computation (it may not be the case if you plan to use the boolean arrays in another context).
This function is called once for each array like this:

```py
'query_A_shift0': toPackedArray((((bigDF.A >= 1) & (bigDF.A < 3))).to_numpy()),
```

Once packed, the array can be computed much more efficiently by working directly on 64-bits integers (64-bits per integers are computed at once). Here is the resulting code:

```py
# See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight
@nb.njit('uint64(uint64)', inline='always')
def popcount64c(x):
    m1  = 0x5555555555555555
    m2  = 0x3333333333333333
    m4  = 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f
    h01 = 0x0101010101010101
    x -= (x >> 1) & m1
    x = (x & m2) + ((x >> 2) & m2)
    x = (x + (x >> 4)) & m4
    return (x * h01) >> 56

# Numba preparation
@nb.njit('uint64(uint64[::1],uint64[::1],uint64[::1],uint64[::1],uint64[::1])', parallel=True)
def computeSubsetLength5(cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4, cond5):
    n = len(cond1)
    assert len(cond2) == n and len(cond3) == n and len(cond4) == n and len(cond5) == n
    subsetLength = 0
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        subsetLength += popcount64c(cond1[i] & cond2[i] & cond3[i] & cond4[i] & cond5[i])
    return subsetLength
```

`popcount64c` counts the number of bits set to 1 in each 64-bits chunks.

Here are results on my 6-core i5-9600KF machine:

```
Reference implementation: 13.41 s
Proposed implementation:   0.38 s
```

The proposed implementation is **35 times** faster than the (already optimized) Numba implementation. The reason why it is much faster than just 8 times is that data should now **fit in the last-level cache of your processor** with is often much faster than the RAM (about 5 times on my machine).

If you when to optimize further this code you can work on **smaller chunks** that fits in the L2 cache and use threads in the combinatoric loop rather than in the still memory bound `computeSubsetLength5` function. This should give you a significant speed-up (I expect at least a x2).

The biggest optimisation to apply then probably comes from the overall **algorithm**. The same logical AND operations are computed several times over and over. **Pre-computing** most of them on the fly while keeping only the most useful ones should significantly speed the algorithm up (I expect a speed-up of x2).

I am pretty sure there are many other optimisations that can be applied on on the overall algorithm. Performing a brute-force is often sufficient to solve a problem but hardly a requirement.

Comment: Hi @Jérôme Richard, your previous speed up helped me a lot back then! Later on the amount of columns grew and the script time raised. I first tried some optimizations on my own, but came back here because I have made no real progress over the past few weeks. So thanks a lot again for your time and answer. Already saw a lot of new information that is going to help me. Will be testing this next week since I then have time to read it thoroughly!

Comment: Hi @Jérôme Richard, in advance of testing upcoming week. I just noticed I used only integers in my queryDict example, my bad.. In my case though I also have floats in some of the boolean arrays. Will the code be able to handle those?

Comment: Ok, the code will probably not support it. However, what are the float values ? 0 and 1? If yes, only the `toPackedArray` needs to be adapted (with minor changes as only a cast should be required). If no, then what would be the meaning of doing a logical AND operation in the original code?

Comment: For example: 'query_A_shift0': ((bigDF.A >= 1) & (bigDF.A < 3)), could be  'query_A_shift0': ((bigDF.A >= 1.25) & (bigDF.A < 3.25)),. With floats I meant the values can be floating-point numbers. Not sure if that is what you meant by 0 and 1. They will have a maximum of 2 decimals. @Jérôme Richard

Comment: Ha ok. I think it does not matter as the final result is a temporary boolean array passed to the function `toPackedArray` whatever the (boolean) condition. So the above code should support this case.

Comment: Hi @Jérôme Richard, I've tested the solution. The speed up is great, thanks again! For the example on my computer it is 4.4 times faster. Afterwards I implemented the code in my personal use-case. Here the solution is 2.1 times faster, I guess because I use more columns. For your answer I think it is good to add that within the for loop, at the "count = .computeSubset.." part, .to_numpy() should be removed. Since the toPackedArray does this now. With regards to smaller chunks, do you then mean slicing the DF into smaller pieces? And is there a way to find the ideal chunk size for the L2 cache?

Comment: Good to know. For the chunks, yes, the idea is to work on a block of rows so that computations can be done in cache. The L2 cache is generally very small. You can get its size on the website of Intel/AMD/etc. (generally from 256KB to 1MB). If M arrays with N boolean items are needed for a given computation, then the overall required cache size will be M*N/8 and this must be significantly smaller than the L2 cache size. For M=5 and with a 256 KB N must be smaller than 400K items. It is safer to set N to 100K~200K items in this case (since caches are not perfect).

Comment: Hi @jérôme-richard, the improvements helped me a lot during various analysis. But since a few weeks I've been trying to further improve the speed with your tips (smaller chunks and pre-computing). Thus far I only managed to improve speed by changing all datatypes in the dataframe to int8 (now has only 0 or 1 values). I did not manage to get the smaller chunks and pre-computing to work yet. Do you by any chance have any advice for studies/blogs/books or other sources I can read to learn more about this concept. I really would like to improve on this subject. Thanks in advance.