# Determining the validity of a multi-hot encoding

Tags: python, numpy, bit-manipulation, numpy-einsum

Suppose I have `N` items and a multi-hot vector of values `{0, 1}` that represents inclusion of these items in a result:

```py
N = 4

# items 1 and 3 will be included in the result
vector = [0, 1, 0, 1]

# item 2 will be included in the result
vector = [0, 0, 1, 0]
```

I'm also provided a matrix of conflicts which indicates which items cannot be included in the result at the same time:

```py
conflicts = [
  [0, 1, 1, 0], # any result that contains items 1 AND 2 is invalid
  [0, 1, 1, 1], # any result that contains AT LEAST 2 items from {1, 2, 3} is invalid
]
```

Given this matrix of conflicts, we can determine the validity of the earlier `vector`s:

```py
# invalid as it triggers conflict 1: [0, 1, 1, 1]
vector = [0, 1, 0, 1]

# valid as it triggers no conflicts
vector = [0, 0, 1, 0]
```

A naive solution to detect whether a given `vector` is "valid" (i.e. does not trigger any conflicts) may be done via a dot product and summation operation in numpy:

```
violation = np.dot(conflicts, vector)
is_valid = np.max(violation) <= 1
```

Are there are more efficient ways to perform this operation, perhaps either via `np.einsum` or by bypassing numpy arrays entirely in favour of bit manipulation?

We assume that the number of vectors being checked can be very large (e.g. up to `2^N` if we evaluate all possibilities) but that only one vector is likely being checked at a time (to avoid generating a matrix of shape up to `(2^N, N)` as input).

Comment: Don't you mean `np.dot(conflicts, vector)` ? Or maybe `np.dot(vector, np.array(conflicts).T)` ? The current one is not valid. In both case `violation` is a 1D array (so there is no `axis=1`).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Good catch, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: you can use **Numba** to optimize `np.dot` to only operate **only on binary values**. More specifically, you can perform **SIMD-like operations** on 8 bytes at once using **64-bit views**.

---

### Converting lists to arrays

First of all, the lists can be efficiently converted to relatively-compact arrays using this approach:

```py
vector = np.fromiter(vector, np.uint8)
conflicts = np.array([np.fromiter(conflicts[i], np.uint8) for i in range(len(conflicts))])
```

This is faster than using the automatic Numpy conversion or `np.array` (there is less check to perform in the Numpy code internally and Numpy, Numpy know what type of array to build and the resulting one is smaller in memory and thus faster to fill). This step can be used to speed up your `np.dot`-based solution.

If the input are already a Numpy array, then check they are of type `np.uint8` or `np.int8`. Otherwise, please cast them to such type using `conflits = conflits.astype(np.uint8)` for example.

---

### First try

Then, one solution could be to use `np.packbits` to pack the input binary values much as possible in an array of bits in memory, and then perform logical ANDs. But it turns out that `np.packbits` is pretty slow. Thus, this solution is not a good idea in the end. In fact, any solution creating temporary arrays with a shape similar to `conflicts` will be slow since writing such an array in memory is generally slower than `np.dot` (which read `conflicts` from memory once).

---

### Using Numba

Since `np.dot` is pretty well optimized, the only solution to defeat it is to use an optimized native code. Numba can be used to generate a native executable code at runtime from a Numpy-based Python code thanks to a just-in-time compiler. The idea is to perform a logical ANDs between `vector` and rows of `conflicts` per block. Conflict are check for each block so to stop the computation as early as possible. Blocks can be efficiently compared by groups of 8 octets by comparing the uint64 views of the two arrays (in a SIMD-friendly way).

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('bool_(uint8[::1], uint8[:,::1])')
def check_valid(vector, conflicts):
    n, m = conflicts.shape
    assert vector.size == m

    for i in range(n):
        block_size = 128 # In the range: 8,16,...,248
        conflicts_row = conflicts[i,:]
        gsum = 0 # Global sum of conflicts
        m_limit = m // block_size * block_size

        for j in range(0, m_limit, block_size):
            vector_block = vector[j:j+block_size].view(np.uint64)
            conflicts_block = conflicts_row[j:j+block_size].view(np.uint64)

            # Matching
            lsum = np.uint64(0) # 8 local sums of conflicts
            for k in range(block_size//8):
                lsum += vector_block[k] & conflicts_block[k]

            # Trick to perform the reduction of all the bytes in lsum
            lsum += lsum >> 32
            lsum += lsum >> 16
            lsum += lsum >> 8
            gsum += lsum & 0xFF

            # Check if there is a conflict
            if gsum >= 2:
                return False

        # Remaining part
        for j in range(m_limit, m):
            gsum += vector[j] & conflicts_row[j]

        if gsum >= 2:
            return False

    return True
```

---

### Results

This is about **9 times faster** than `np.dot` on my machine for a large `conflicts` array of shape `(16, 65536)` (without conflicts). The time to convert lists is not included in both cases. When there are conflicts, the provided solution is much faster since it can early stop the computation.

Theoretically, the computation should be even faster, but the Numba JIT do not succeed to vectorize the loop using SIMD instructions. That being said, it seems the same issue appears for `np.dot`. If the arrays are even bigger, you can parallelize the computation of the blocks (at the expense of a slower computation if the function return False).

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! Regarding your first solution, would it be safe to assume that the logical ANDs you alluded to would be even faster if we were able to mandate that the inputs were already in the form of integers representing binary values that correspond to the examples I provided?

Comment: Having input arrays already compressed would help a lot (mainly for huge arrays) but the Numpy solution was still a bit slow (especially compared to the Numba one). Mixing Numba with compressed array should help (though the code will be more complex). It is especially true if multiple threads are used. If the array are really huge, then it may be better to write a native C/C++ module.

Comment: By the way, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69081194/12939557) past answer might be interesting to you.