# Determining the validity of a multi-hot encoding using bit manipulation

Tags: python, c, bit-manipulation

Suppose I have `N` items and a binary number that represents inclusion of these items in a result:

```py
N = 4

# items 1 and 3 will be included in the result
vector = 0b0101

# item 2 will be included in the result
vector = 0b0010
```

I'm also provided a list conflicts which indicates which items cannot be included in the result at the same time:

```py
conflicts = [
  0b0110, # any result that contains items 1 AND 2 is invalid
  0b0111, # any result that contains AT LEAST 2 items from {1, 2, 3} is invalid
]
```

Given this list of conflicts, we can determine the validity of the earlier `vector`s:

```py
# invalid as it triggers conflict 1: [0, 1, 1, 1]
vector = 0b0101

# valid as it triggers no conflicts
vector = 0b0010
```

How can bit manipulation be used to determine validity of a vector or large list of vectors against a list of conflicts in this context?

The solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72135013/1195935) already gets us most of the way there but I'm unsure how to adapt it to the integer use case (to avoid numpy arrays and numba entirely).

Comment: Why is this tagged Python and C? Which language do you want an answer for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
N = 4

# items 1 and 3 will be included in the result
vector = 0b0101

# item 2 will be included in the result
vector = 0b0010

conflicts = [
  0b0110, # any result that contains items 1 AND 2 is invalid
  0b0111, # any result that contains AT LEAST 2 items from {1, 2, 3} is invalid
]

def find_conflict(vector, conflicts):
    found_conflict = False
    for v in conflicts:
        result = vector & v # do a logical AND operation
        if result != 0: # there are common elements
            number_of_bits_set = bin(result).count("1") # count number of common elements
            if number_of_bits_set >= 2: # check common limit for detection of invalid vectors
                found_conflict = True
                print(f"..Conflict between {bin(vector)} and {bin(v)}: {bin(result)}")
    if found_conflict:
        print(f"Conflict found for {bin(vector)}.")
    else:
        print(f"No conflict found for {bin(vector)}.")

# invalid as it triggers conflict 1: [0, 1, 1, 1]
vector = 0b0101
find_conflict(vector, conflicts)

# valid as it triggers no conflicts
vector = 0b0010
find_conflict(vector, conflicts)
```

```
$ python3 pythontest.py
..Conflict between 0b101 and 0b111: 0b101
Conflict found for 0b101.
No conflict found for 0b10.
$
```